# What happens to a stateful operation when a kafka broker goes down?

Tags: apache-kafka

Let us imagine that a stateful operation is undergoing like:

1. Aggregation

or

2. Windowing

and then the responsible broker inside a cluster goes down for some reason.

In this case, what will happen to the operation?

Does the operation get entirely lost and must be retried?

Or

Can I continue the operation when a new leader broker gets nominated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable fault tolerance for the state stores. Please refer the [doc](https://kafka.apache.org/36/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#fault-tolerant-state-stores). How will your operation will continue depends on did you enable or disable fault tolerance.